# Find the area between $y=x; y=2x; y=1/x; y=3/x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area between $y=x; y=2x; y=1/x; y=3/x$ using the substitution $(x,y)=(\frac{u}{v},uv)$

I made a sketch but don't see how I can make use of the substitution given, to help.

Comment: I don't think you've made use of the substitutions given. Although they are weird ones, they do work

Comment: The substitution looks like a good idea. The domain will transform to a rectangle in the $uv$ plane.

Comment: @mickep Do the axis after the transformation have to be linear or does $u^2$ and $v^2$ suffice?

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. In this case that transformation will give a rectangle. But you could also do other changes of variables, as abel does here, leading to non-rectangular domains. The only general idea is: Do a substitution that will make your problem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easier to find the area using polar coordinates. the transformation between polar and cartesian are given by $$x = r \cos t, y = r \sin t, y = 1/x \to r\sin t = \frac1{r\cos t} \to r^2 = \frac 1{\sin t\cos t} .$$ the area is $\frac 12 \int_{t_1}^{t_2} (r_2^2 - r_1^2) \, dt$. that is

$$\frac12\int_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1} 2} \left(\frac 3{\sin t\cos t} - \frac 1{\sin t \cos t}\right) \, dt  =2\int_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1} 2}\csc 2t\, dt=  \ln(\csc 2t + \cot 2t)\big|_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1} 2}
=\ln 2.$$

Comment: How did you get to those bounds?

Comment: @VincentTwin,   $y = kx$ translates to $t = \tan^{-1}(y/x)$ if $(x,y)$ is in the first quadrant.

Comment: @VincentTwin, i made a mistake earlier. it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

$x=\frac{u}{v}, y=uv\implies u^2=xy\;$ and $\;v^2=\frac{y}{x}$, so

$1\le u^2\le3\;, \;1\le v^2\le2 \implies 1\le u\le\sqrt{3},\;1\le v\le\sqrt{2}$.

Since $\displaystyle\begin{vmatrix}x_u &x_v\\y_u & y_v\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{1}{v} &-\frac{u}{v^2}\\v & u\end{vmatrix}=\frac{2u}{v}$,

$\displaystyle A=\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}\frac{2u}{v}dudv=\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\frac{2}{v}dv=\big[2\ln v\big]_1^{\sqrt{2}}=2\ln\sqrt{2}=\ln 2$.

---

Alternatively, $xy=k\implies r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta=k\implies r^2=\frac{k}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}=2k\csc 2\theta$,

so using polar coordinates gives $\displaystyle A=\int_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1}2}\frac{1}{2}\left(6\csc 2\theta-2\csc2\theta\right)d\theta=\int_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1}2}2\csc2\theta d\theta$

$\displaystyle=\int_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1}2} \frac{2}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}d\theta=\int_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1}2}\frac{\sec^2\theta}{\tan\theta}d\theta=\big[\ln(\tan\theta)\big]_{\pi/4}^{\tan^{-1}2}=\ln 2-\ln1=\ln 2$.